# Strange crashes on android: com.xkcopyrightpage.Entra$O0000000.run and EdHooker_.hook

Tags: java, android, crash

After releasing recent update of my app, strange crashes start to appear in Firebase crashlytics related to `com.xkcopyrightpage` package which not belongs to my app, or any of its dependencies. Said crashes now most frequent ones, overtaking by great margin crashes in my own code and used libraries combined.

I tried to google for `com.xkcopyrightpage` with no success.

Is my app runs under some unusual instrumentation software by someone?

Exact tracebacks:

(I definitely don't have Activity to handle such intents, and no intent to handle it)

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mqqapi://card/show_pslcard?src_type=internal&version=1&uin=257540561&card_type=group&source=qrcode }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2007)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4587)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4545)
       at EdHooker_.hook(:141)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4906)
       at EdHooker_.hook(:135)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4874)
       at com.xkcopyrightpage.Dialog.O0000000(Dialog.java:5)
       at com.xkcopyrightpage.Dialog$O00000OO.onClick(Dialog.java:1)
       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Again, I definitely don't have or intent to have mentioned activity in my app.

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.nyrds.pixeldungeon.ml/com.xkcopyrightpage.activity.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2079)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1737)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5389)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5347)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5733)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5686)
       at com.xkcopyrightpage.Entra$O0000000.run(Entra.java:20)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but whenever I experienced issues like this, they were related to librarys or SDKs that I added in the app. The solutions are usually available in the `issues` section of the library's github repository. If you don't find the solution, you can always open an issue there. From the log, I'm **assuming** that the problem is with the library `NYRDS/remixed-dungeon`. GitHub link: https://github.com/NYRDS/remixed-dungeon